# Will this make my SSD never go idle/to sleep?

Tags: ssd, battery, macbook, google-drive

I have an External SSD ([SanDisk Portable 500](https://shop.westerndigital.com/products/portable-drives/sandisk-extreme-usb-3-1-ssd#SDSSDE60-250G-G25)) always plugged in on my **MacBook 2019 13'** *(with 128GB internal storage)*.

I synced my Google Drive Folder w/ Backup & Sync to this SSD.

Every time I insert my SSD, my battery drowns very quickly (almost 3x faster than normal web browsing). Actively using it or keeping it idle.

When Google Drive is syncing, the SSD goes warm (which means it is processing a lot of information), when Google Drive stops syncing, it becomes *Updated* (check image below).

[image]

Even tho it is updated and I am not using the SSD, it stills consumes a lot of battery.

**Question is:** does this Google Drive ***Updated*** state keeps "using" (reading/writing) my SSD and making it a battery sucker?

I feel it is drowning too much battery when not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google Backup and Sync reads every few seconds to see if anything's changed, and writes whenever something changes from outside.

One option is to not keep the SSD plugged in all of the time, but just when you actually use it.

Another option is to kill the Google Backup and Sync app when you're not using it, so that it's not accessing the SSD all the time.  There is a Pause option built into the Google Backup and Sync program.  There might be other apps using the SSD.

Another option is to use a powered USB hub.

Another option is to keep the Google Backup and Sync on the internal drive, which must be on anyway.  If you're pressed for space, then you can choose which folders to sync, and avoid syncing the biggest folders.